# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)

Tags: java

I have this problem when coding java and do not know how to solve it. Any help would be great. Here's part of my code. And the error is at the last.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = null;

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

        n = scan.nextInt(); //line 37
        m = scan.nextInt();

        if (n == -1 && m == -1) {
            break;
        }
        init();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            name = scan.next();
            course.put(name, i);
        }
        ...
    p[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 12; ++i)
        p[i] = p[i - 1] << 1;

    input();//line 117
    solve();


Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Graduate.graduateProj.input(graduateProj.java:37)
at Graduate.graduateProj.main(graduateProj.java:117)
```

Comment: Are you sure that input tokens provided to Scanner are of expected type?What is the type of "n"?

Comment: InputMismatchException  means you dont provide the needed type: you parse int but input something else.

Comment: n is a public static int

Answer (score 1):

You'll get an `InputMismatchException` if you try to call `Scanner::nextInt` on a string that can't be parsed to an int.